# Create table in SNOWFLAKE With Time stamp in UTC

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I m trying to create. stable in snowflake, making sure that time stamp is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() but in UTC. Here is the syntax I am using;

```
 ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBOT(
 ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 PREDICTED_PROBABILITY FLOAT,
TIME_PREDICTED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But after inserting rows into this table, I am still getting the time in America/Los Angeles time format.

```
479291 0.5797053576  2021-06-16 13:56:26.595
```

Can I kindly get help on how to get timestamp in UTC? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for timestamps and converting between timezones.
I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with the [three different kinds of timestamps](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz)

This is generally what we use though:
`CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', current_timestamp())::timestamp_ntz`

The convert should get you to UTC, regardless of what timezone your Snowflake instance is set to by default. And the timestamp_ntz (no time zone) is the timestamp without any timezone information, which works well if you know it's always going to be UTC.

Without knowing a lot more about your use case I'd have a hard time giving a wholehearted recommendation on which of the timezone data types you should be using. This code should only need a minor tweak to change the data type.

**EDIT:** More full test example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBOT(
 ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
TIME_PREDICTED1 TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::timestamp_ntz,
TIME_PREDICTED2 TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::timestamp_ntz
);

insert into DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBOT (account_id)
select 1;

select * from DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBOT;
```

**Edit 2:** I think the reason your version isn't working is because the Session timezone isn't "remembered" by the `default` constraint. That `default` will use whatever the session timezone is for the insert queries in the future, which is another reason that it's good to specify the timezone explicitely here.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. But this will work with the SELECT statement. What I  am looking for is when the data is inserted into the table the CURRENT TIMESTAMP shd be in UTC format. Hope my question is making sense. Will be happy to clarify.

Comment: added a more complete example using my version.
You can play with the data type for both the column type and casting depending on your use case.

Comment: If you're still seeing issues, then it might be whatever process is doing the insert that is putting a value in, which will ignore the default constraint. That's something that the table itself can't account for.

Answer (score 1):

David's Answer Works. You have to change the `data type` to `TIMESTAMPNTZ` too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBO (
      ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , PREDICTED_PROBABILITY FLOAT
    , TIME_PREDICTED TIMESTAMPNTZ
        DEFAULT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())::TIMESTAMPNTZ
);


INSERT INTO DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBO (
      ACCOUNT_ID  
    , PREDICTED_PROBABILITY
  ) VALUES (  
          1
        , 24.444444
);

SELECT * FROM DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES_DATAROBO;
-- RESULT as local time is 2022-12-06 21:02:29.071, so it gets converted.
-- 1    24.444444   2022-12-07 04:02:29.071
```